# breaking the loop in bash programming

Tags: linux, bash

This code is working fine with me I am new to bash programming I want loop to run only once and I dont want loop to run and watermark the all videos. Instead I want to break the loop when first video is done.

```
#!/bin/bash


#!!!!!!VARIABLES!!!!!!
VIDEOS_PATH='/home/danny/public_html/videowork/'
LOGO_PATH='/home/danny/public_html/watermark_pics/'
DATABASE_INFORMATION='/home/danny/public_html/videowork/db.txt'
#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
if find $VIDEOS_PATH -name '*.mp4' 2> /dev/null
then
for file in $(find $VIDEOS_PATH -name '*.mp4')
do
echo "User: ".$(whoami)
echo "File: "$file" has been detected"
sitename=$(echo $file | awk -F $VIDEOS_PATH '{print $2}')
sitename=$(echo $sitename |awk -F '/' '{print $1}')
echo "File sitename is: "$sitename
logo=$LOGO_PATH$sitename.png
echo "Watermark picture has been located in: "$logo
echo "Encoding "$file" to /home/"$sitename"/public_html/yt/"$(basename $file)
    ffmpeg -i $file -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -vf "movie=$logo [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" /home/$sitename/public_html/yt/$(basename $file)
thumbnail=$(basename $file .mp4)
thumbnail=$VIDEOS_PATH$sitename"/"$(echo $thumbnail).jpg
mv $thumbnail /home/$sitename/public_html/yt/
rm $file
echo "/home/$sitename/public_html/yt/$(basename $file)"
    for line in $(cat $DATABASE_INFORMATION)
    do
    database=$(echo $line | awk -F '|' '{print $1}')
    password=$(echo $line | awk -F '|' '{print $2}')
    echo "Database detected: "$database
    echo "Password: "$password
    videoid=$(basename $file .mp4)
    if [[ $(echo $database) == $(echo $sitename) ]]
    then
        php -f /home/danny/public_html/videowork/database_job.php -- $(echo $database) $(echo $password) $(echo $videoid)
        #echo "php -f database_job.php -- "$(echo $database)"  "$(echo $password)" "$(echo $videoid)
    fi
    done
done
   fi
```

If I add "break" before last fi? would it be fine? I tried but it didnt work well

Comment: You want it before the last done, not before the last fi.

Comment: You have multiple `for` loops in the code. Please specify which one you are trying to break.

Comment: ...also, -1 for asking a question that won't ever be useful to someone other than you. (codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for those; StackOverflow's mission is to build a reusable knowledge base of canonical questions and answers). If we still had the "Too Localized" close reason, it would be precisely on-point.

Comment: For running the loop only once, what you achieve with break before done, why do you use a loop construct at all? just letting your code run straight through has the same effect.

Comment: ...also, see #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls; `for file in $(find ...)` will never work correctly with filenames with spaces &c.

Comment: By the way -- repeated `echo $line | awk ...` is silly and inefficient. Use use a single `read` statement: `IFS='|' read database password _ <<<"$line"`

Comment: continue starts next iteration - but break before done behaves as if the for..do...done construct wouldn't exist, as it runs once, then breaks. same as linear code.

Comment: ...also, non-exported (shell-local) variable names should be lowercase to avoid namespace collisions with builtins or environment variables.

Comment: I just want to run the loop only once the first loop for -->    file in $(find $VIDEOS_PATH -name '*.mp4') I want after finding first video and watermarking it. It should break the loop

Comment: @user3720709, as the BashPitfalls page I linked to tells you, `for file in $(anything)` is buggy. Don't do that.

Comment: ...also related: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 0):

Using a looping construct only to break after the first iteration is silly. Instead, don't use that construct at all. For instance, with bash 4.x or newer, you can completely avoid use of `find` entirely:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob
videos=( "$VIDEOS_PATH"/**/*.mp4 )
(( ${#videos[@]} )) || { echo "No videos found" >&2; exit 1; }
file=${videos[0]}
# ...transcode "$file" here
```

For compatibility with bash 3.x, one might change this a bit to still use `find` (albeit with `-print0` and an appropriate read construct to handle filenames with unusual characters):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS= read -r -d '' file < <(find "$VIDEOS_PATH" -name '*.mp4' -print0)
[[ $file ]] || { echo "No videos found" >&2; exit 1; }
# ...transcode "$file" here
```